# Image not unlink from folder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am upload some files into my folder when i unlink the file doesn't unlink, what are the file name with space doesn't unlink and what are the file name have Parentheses doesn't unlink.

eg:- img4 (2).jpg, sample file.pdf

Any one give me a solution...

Thanks

Comment: try to remove white space from string using this `$str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $filename);` or you can use `str_replace(' ', '', $filename);` and than use unlink.

Comment: Ya working perfect Thanks

Comment: you welcome ;) . If possible please vote the answer might be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solutions.

[Php unlink() returning errors with encoded filepaths containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043884/php-unlink-returning-errors-with-encoded-filepaths-containing-spaces)

Try

```
unlink(urldecode($filepath));
```

or

```
$filepath = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $filepath);
unlink($filepath);
```